# Creating simple table (picture included)

Tags: tables

I'm quite struggling. I'd like to centralize pretty much everything except Table X, Three long words and the left panel (Bla of... + abcde). Thanks for your suggestions.

So far I came up with this:

```
\begin{table}

\caption{name}

\centering 

\begin{tabular}{llllllll}

\hline

~ & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Three long words}   \\ 

Blue of bla of ble  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \hline

A       &  10.2  & 10.2  &  10.2  &  10.2  &  10.2    \\

B       &   111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

But it doesn't work well. What I want to create:

[image: What I want to create]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Generally, you want numbers to align on their decimal point.  In this case, that would be right aligned, as they already are.  That way, a quick glance tells you the magnitudes involved.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one possible solution. See my input and corresponding output below.

I made a couple of improvements, including the use of the `booktabs` package (for nicer-looking rules), and the `siunitx` package (for decimal alignment), as suggested by [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146259/creating-simple-table-picture-included#comment331580_146259).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}    % only to show the position
                                    % of the tabular on the page
\usepackage{booktabs}   % this package promotes good tabular style
\usepackage{caption}    % for customising caption style
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for decimal alignment

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \captionsetup%
    {%
        singlelinecheck = off,  % for correct just. of single-line captions
        justification   = raggedright,
        labelfont       = bf,
    }
    \centering%
    \bfseries
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.7\textwidth}       % A minipage is convenient here;
                                            % its width may have to be adjusted.
        \caption{name}%
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l SSSSS }        % @{} removes the extra horizontal space
            \toprule
                                & \multicolumn{5}{l}{Three long words}  \\
            \cmidrule{2-6}

            Blue of bla of ble  & 1     & 2     & 3     & 4     & 5     \\
            \midrule
            A                   & 10.2  & 10.2  &  10.2 & 10.2  &  10.2 \\
            B                   & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you expectet somethin like this (the changes marked):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}

\caption{name}

\centering 

%\begin{tabular}{llllllll}
\begin{tabular}{l*5{c}}
\hline

%~ & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Three long words}   \\ 
~ & \multicolumn{5}{l}{ Three long words}   \\ 
\cline{2-6} % PS
Blue of bla of ble  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ \hline

A       &  10.2  & 10.2  &  10.2  &  10.2  &  10.2    \\

B       &   111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 & 111.2 \\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]